# Написать драйвер PCI устройства в C# 5, используя WDK 7

Tags: c#, windows, драйвер

Вполняю задание по написанию PCI device драйвера. Язык реализации - C# 5. Возник вопрос -есть ли какая-то документация для новичка по этой теме и как подключить WDK в C# ?

Comment: c# 5? Последняя версия .Net вроде 4.5?!

Comment: >c# 5? Последняя версия .Net вроде 4.5?!

Википедию хоть почитали бы? прежде чем глупости говорить. номер версии C# очень слабо связан с номером версии .NET. И да, вы удивитесь, но текущая версия языка - 5, а .NET - 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сколько я помню, то никак. Драйвера работают в режиме ядра. C#  не умеет компилировать "ядерные" программы. Драйвера пользовательского режима ограчены работой только с USB ( возможно, за 4 года что-то поменялось)